# Is it well-defined to modify an unordered_set inside a foreach loop if one breaks out immediately after?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, unordered-set

Consider the following program. The loop in the middle attempts to replace exactly one item with one other item, and then breaks out of the loop.

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    std::unordered_set<int> foo{1,2,3};
    printf("Set Before:\n");
    for (int x : foo)
        printf("%d\n", x);
    for (int x : foo) {
        if (x == 1) {
            foo.erase(1);
            foo.insert(4);
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("Set After:\n");
    for (int x : foo)
        printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

**Is the code above well-defined?**

Comment: Incrementing an iterator to a deleted entry, sounds like NO

Comment: Its good general practice. In this case it makes little (if any difference) but C++ is based on types. Changing the type in a single location can cause cascading affects through the code so best to use references and non copying where possible so you can change the code in one place and still have the most efficient code.

Comment: `std::find_if` seems more idiomatic (assuming you really have to do linear search).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is the code above well-defined?

Yes. The erase would invalidate the iterator you're on right now, which would make the subsequent increment of it undefined behavior - but there is no subsequent increment, since you're `break`ing unconditionally.

---

Although instead of looping over each element until you find `1`, you can just try to erase it and see if that did anything:

```
if (foo.erase(1)) {
    foo.insert(4);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`for(type var:target)` loops are defined as being equivalent to:

```
{
  auto&& __target = target;
  auto&& __start = __magic_begin(__target);
  auto&& __finish = __magic_end(__target);
  for (; __start != __finish; ++__start) {
    type var = *__start;
    __body_of_loop_here__
  }
}
```

where `__magic_begin` is a magic function that does some stuff to find the begin iterator, whose details do not matter here.  (also, `__` prefixed names are just for illustration purposes).

As your code is defined with the above transformation, it is defined without it.

Most things in the standard are not this clear cut; this one really is.

There are even bugs caused by the above transformation.  For example, if `target` has temporaries that aren't the result of the expression, their lifetime ends before the `__start` iterator is created.

Comment: As an aside, is there any reason not to define `__magic_begin` and `__magic_end` in terms of  `std::begin` and `std::end`, also introduced in C++11? cppreference's page on [range-based for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) doesn't mention them, though the explanation sounds nearly identical.

Comment: @alterigel Yes.  It never calls `std::begin` unless the type is within `namespace std`.  This is a language feature, it does not depend on the `std` library.  There are subtle differences as well, but mainly it was about a dependency inversion (library depends on language, language does not depend on library).